# clustering analysis\ data is in right skewed

Tags: clustering, normalization, z-score

what normalization technique(mean normalization/min  max/zscore) is prefered to apply k-means clustering   scope of data: right skewed  variables are different  scales & magnitude(days,counts) also considered ordinal data in algorithm by onehoten coding

Answer (score 1):

You may start by trying to apply a logarithm transformation to your data and check the skewness of the transformation.

If you want a more general transformation, you can use the [Box-Cox transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transform#Box%E2%80%93Cox_transformation) to correct for the skewness of your data (positive or negative).

Note that in both cases, your data must contain only positive values.

If the data is skewed to the right, you might use a value of the parameter $\lambda < 1$. Try a few values to see which will give you a less skewed distribution.

---

If your variable, let's call it $X$ has positive and negative values and you may do the following steps:

1. Compute the minimum $m_X$ and the median $\tilde{X}$.
2. Compute the $Y$ variable for some $\lambda \neq 0$ using the formula:
   $$
   Y = \tilde{X} \left( 1 + \frac{ \left( \frac{X + m_X}{\tilde{X} + m_X} \right) ^\lambda - 1}{\lambda} \right)
   $$
   or for $\lambda = 0$:
   $$
   Y = \tilde{X} \left( 1 + \log \left( \frac{X + m_X}{\tilde{X} + m_X} \right) \right)
   $$

The transformed variable $Y$ will preserve the order of $X$ and will have the same median ($\tilde{Y} = \tilde{X}$), however, other statistics may differ substantially, such as the minimum, maximum or the standard deviation.